# Selenium find_element_by_id() doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium

When I go to https://www.youtube.com with Selenium and try to select the search bar using find_element_by_id() and using "masthead-search-term" as the ID, I get an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\Projects\Python Projects\test.py", line 9, in <module>
driver.find_element_by_id("masthead-search-term")
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 341, in find_element_by_id
return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 843, in find_element
'value': value})['value']
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"masthead-search-term"}
```

Why is that? Here's the code:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\Applications\chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("masthead-search-term")
```

Comment: What is the error? which element u locate

Comment: Use wait to locate

Comment: That id doesn't exist on the page, even after page load. I'm not sure where you got that. The id of the searchbar is `search`, `<input id="search" ...>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take care of a couple of things as follows:

1. While working with the Chrome browser, try to open in *maximized* mode, with disabling *infobars* and *extensions* which enables you to use the maximum available [`Viewport`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).
2. Once you access the URL *https://www.youtube.com*, either wait for the loader to disappear or wait for the search box to be clickable.
3. Ensure the locators you are using are unique and correct. With *Dev Tools* of the [Firefox Quantum 57.0b3 (64-bit)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=YIywpvHewc0) browser, the [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression of the search box seems to be `//input[@id='search']`.
4. Here is the working code block with browser:

   ```
   import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

   options = Options()
   options.add_argument("start-maximized")
   options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
   options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
   driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
   search_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
       EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='search']"))
   )
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='search']").send_keys("Selenium")
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct. Use some wait to locate the element. Try this code:

```python
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\Applications\chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_id("masthead-search-term").send_keys("Nature")
```

This is Java code (set *geckodriver* if required):

```java
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("masthead-search-term")).sendKeys("Nature");
```

You can also use the name as a locator:

```java
driver.findElement(By.name("search_query")).sendKeys("Nature");
```

Comment: What is the error, what u exaclty want are u want to search. Can i give you java code, You will convert in python. Try now I miss the quote

Comment: The error is still the same. It cannot find the element even though it is there. It would be nice if you sent me the Java code. We'll see if that works

Comment: IS it work? You can also locate it with name as "search_query". it is worked for  me

Comment: @NorthernGuy try it and let me know,

Answer (score 1):

```
Selenium 4.3.0
* Deprecated find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_* are now removed (#10712)
* Deprecated Opera support has been removed (#10630)
* Fully upgraded from python 2x to 3.7 syntax and features (#10647)
* Added a devtools version fallback mechanism to look for an older version when mismatch occurs (#10749)
* Better support for co-operative multi inheritance by utilising super() throughout
* Improved type hints throughout
```

You need to import Selenium WebDriver using this code:

`from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

Old API:

```
find_element_by_id(‘id’)
find_element_by_name(‘name’)
find_element_by_xpath(‘xpath’)
```

New API:

```
find_element(By.ID, ‘id’)
find_element(By.NAME, ‘name’)
find_element(By.XPATH,‘xpath’)
```

Source: Fixing Selenium AttributeError: ‘WebDriver’ object has no attribute ‘find_element_by_xpath’

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to find the search bar and send keys and search. There doesn't exist an element with ID *'masthead-search-term'*.

I would suggest a better way to do this is:

```
search_query = your_search_query
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=' + search_query)
```

If you want to do it in the manner you have done, then it will look something like:

```
driver.get(http://www.youtube.com)
driver.find_element_by_id('search').sendKeys('Your_search_query')
driver.find_element_by_id('search-icon-legacy').click()
```

One of the more interesting ways is to use Action Chains:

```
driver.get(http://www.youtube.com)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys('Your_Search_Query')
actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
actions.perform()
```

Comment: Element is there @Nihaal

Comment: Go for action Chains method it will work and you don't need to find the element

Answer (score 0):

It is a browser issue. When I use Chrome, Firefox or Edge I cannot find the element. When I use Internet Explorer it is found.

When you use the IEDriver it probably will work but with the ChromeDriver it will not.

Comment: Element is there @koen

Comment: The element is there when you initial load the website? And you did not click anything?

Comment: After click any element it is still there

Comment: Even I couldn't find the element with the mentioned ID on chrome. The search field ID seems to be `search`.

Answer (score -1):

As the exception states, there isn't any element on the page with `id="masthead-search-term"`.

Make sure you are looking for the correct id by inspecting the page DOM. Look for the id attribute of the search bar input element.

I think the search bar input element id is `search`.

Comment: Nope. Checked it using inspect element. Its id IS "masthead-search-term"

Comment: @NorthernGuy id is there

Comment: Re *"by inspecting the page DOM"*: How exactly? Answers are expected to be practical, not just hints.